# Setup Gatling performance tests in same project as production code

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, project-structure

I would like to move our performance Gatling tests from a separate project (where they are now) into the same project as our source code and normal tests.

Ideally, I would like to have the following structure:

```
root-project
|
|--src
    |
    |--main
    |   |
    |   |--scala
    |   |--resources
    |--test
    |   |
    |   |--scala
    |   |--resources
    |--performance
    |   |
    |   |--scala
    |   |--resources
```

The performance tests will be under `src/performance` and you should be able to run them like so:

```
sbt gatling:test
```

Has anyone done that? How should I structure my SBT build file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Gatling sbt plugin](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/extensions/sbt_plugin/): it provides exactly what you're looking for, including the ability to run commands such as `gatling:test` and to specify the location of your Gatling simulations within your project structure. More information is in the linked documentation, and there is a simple project demonstrating how to configure and use the plugin [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-sbt-plugin-demo).

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am using the Gatling sbt plugin, and I tried to play around with it so that it behaves as I described but didn't manage unfortunately (probably because I'm not too comfortable with SBT in general).

Comment: It looks like the reason that I wasn't able to do that is because currently (October 2017) there is a bug in the Gatling SBT plugin.
https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3301
So at the moment this is not really possible.